# how to use azure front door to route traffic using wildcards in path

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

We want to set up domain.com so to route based on path, using wildcards like this:

for most cases, domain.com/* routes to one resource, keeping original domain
BUT
if URL is domain.com/blog/*, it redirects to blog.domain.com/* at another resource. Basically, we want to take whatever comes after /blog/ in the first URL and append it to blog.domain.com in the second URL.

Is there a way to reliably do that using routes and rule sets in Front Door?

I tried setting up 2 routes within an endpoint:

1. domain.com/* routes to origin group that contains our sites main static web app. Origin path is blank.
2. domain is domain.com, patterns to match is /blog/* routes to origin group that contains custom url blog.domain.com. origin path is /*

Seems like it works sometimes, but not always. domain.com/blog does not go to blog.domain.com. Some specific paths/pages on the blog redirect properly, but others do not.

I have tried with rule sets, but haven't been able to get it to take only part of the path (everything AFTER /blog/) instead of just all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to reliably do that using routes and rule sets in Front Door?**

**Yes**, we can route the specific requests that match a routing rule. I have tried to replicate the same in local; here is the routing rule engine configuration for backend pool 1 and backend pool 2.

1. if it was wildcard *, all traffic will be route to that particular route i.e main static web page.

[image]

2. Create second route configuration for blog portal.
   [image]

When incoming request comes as domain.com -> its turns to first route rule and load static web app
If incoming request comes as domain.com/blog/ -> it turns to second route rule and load respective backend endpoint.

reference [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching?pivots=front-door-classic#path-matching) for more information